# How do you persist the cookie with the Jetty Http Client

Tags: java, http, jetty

The Jetty client is pretty good at what it does but it is not clear to me how can I create something like a cookiejar which will be updated on every time the server sends a new cookie header? Is there such a thing?

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I was hoping that there was already a tested solution that comes with Jetty. I can do that myself obviously but it just adds more stuff to the code base which I try to keep as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Java 6, you can use a [CookieManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html) if you're using UrlConnection. There are a few standard implementations that might do what you want. If using another http client, there's probably a similar facility, but you can always get cookies from the responses and add them on the following requests.

Comment: I ended up using the CookieManager and manually doing the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have to do it manually: use the [addRequestHeader](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html#addRequestHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to set your Cookie headers and use the [onResponseHeader](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html#onResponseHeader%28org.mortbay.io.Buffer,%20org.mortbay.io.Buffer%29) callback to listen for `Set-Cookie` response headers and then store those yourself for reuse later.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is just a special HTTP header. It is up to client to store it. So, if you are implementing client application (using some API), store cookie yourself. Retrieve cookie after each request, check their expiration time and save on disk if needed. Plain text file or properties format may be used.